# Handle the FormClosed event in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this button with the code:

```
   private void button22_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Separare sp = new Separare(dataGridView1,label_pin.Tag.ToString(),label_pin.Text);
        sp.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ClosedForm);
        sp.Show();

    }
```

The FormClosedEventHandler looks like this:

```
   DataTable bon_temp = bon_tempTableAdapter.GetDataByTable(label_pin.Tag.ToString());

        foreach (DataRow row in bon_temp.Rows)
        {
            AddRow(row.ItemArray[3].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[4]), Convert.ToDecimal(row.ItemArray[5]));
            Console.WriteLine(row.ItemArray[3].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[4]), Convert.ToDecimal(row.ItemArray[5]));
        }

        bon_tempTableAdapter.DeleteQuery(label_pin.Tag.ToString());
```

where the AddRow method adds rows to DataGridView. My problem is that when i close the sp form the rows are not added to the DataGridView.

Comment: Why are you writing to the console in a WinForms app?

Comment: Probably instead of using Debug.WriteLine, since in a WinForms App, Console.WriteLine will write to the VS console.

Comment: Where is AddRow defined?

Comment: @M.Babcock i wonder why ... think about it!

Comment: @BenHoffstein. The AddRow method works fine. I mean i call it when the form loads and it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FormClosed` occurs whenever the user closes the form, **after** the form **has been closed** and specifies the close reason.

The reason for your code not working might be that some controls on the form are already destroyed...

I suggest you use `FormClosing` event which occurs whenever the user closes the form, **before** the form has been closed and specifies the close reason.

Example code (it is very similar to what you did above):

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.MyMainForm_FormClosing);

...

private void MyMainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  //your code goes here
  //optionally, you can get or set e.Cancel which gets or sets a value indicating that the event should be cancelled; in this case the form won't close if you cancel it here
  //or, you can check e.CloseReason which gets a value that indicates why the form is being closed (this is an enum Systems.Windows.Forms.CloseReason)
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a standard FormClosing example ?

Comment: @Emil: am adaugat un mic exemplu, dar e ff similar cu ce ai scris deja. :) Succes.